# Currious 'state' query param behaviour with angular2 Router

Tags: angular, angular2-router

I don't find any documentation on this precious behaviour of Angular 2 Router : if I load my app with a 'state' query param, the router automatically navigates to the given state.

I found this by chance looking for a solution to my problem, but I need to parse some other query params and here I'm loosing them.

For example : `http://my.app/?state=#/screen1&anotherParam=something` automatically "redirect" my application to `http://my.app/#/screen1`, then I'm loosing `anotherParam`.

Is this a undocumented feature or a bug ? Or do you see any page I missed about this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13806

As a workaround you could add a guard that covers all routes, when the guard is called store the params in a shared service and provide them this way to interested components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your suggestion "guard that covers all routes" will finally solve my real problem. But my post was about the magic feature with 'state' query param...

Comment: What does "the router automatically navigates to the given state" even mean? How do your routes look like?

Comment: I'm using hash strategy.  "the router automatically navigates to the given state" i.e "to the given route"

Comment: No idea what you mean. One of the main features of the router is to allow to create bookmarks for application states. If you click a bookmark to a specific route or enter the URL directly the router navigates to this route. Is this what you mean?

Comment: OK I was wrong, my hash was not encoded so I was in the issue you point. Thanks